# How could I get a crash log from the future in the Google Dev Console?

Tags: exception, google-developers-console

Maybe I'm going crazy...

I got a crash log in the Google Dev Console:

```
5 Feb 02:42 on app version 10
Google Emulator (generic_x86), 4096MB RAM, Android 8.0
Report 1 of 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at business.dots.android.collection.ui.detail.redeem.states.RxStateMachine.register (RxStateMachine.kt)
  at business.dots.android.collection.ui.detail.redeem.states.UIState.<init> (UIState.kt:15)
  at business.dots.android.collection.ui.detail.redeem.states.UIStateIncomplete.<init> (UIStateIncomplete.kt:9)
  at business.dots.android.collection.ui.detail.redeem.RedeemFragment.onCreateView (RedeemFragment.kt:58)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2261)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1419)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1750)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1819)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:797)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManager.java:2590)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:2377)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:2332)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:2239)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManager.java:700)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6541)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The thing is that app version 10 was released back in 2017.

As of now, the class `RxStateMachine` does not exist in the release version.

I introduced the class around the 5th of February but i never released a version including the class.

Even if Google had a time machine and this exception is from the future, this would not be possible since I would have to use the next version code (11) in order to release a new version^^

So my question is...how is that possible?

But maybe I'm going crazy...

Comment: Are you sure that you did not release a version 10 with the new class? I can't see your log, or your source codes, or anything... Maybe a quick release for a bug fix?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure, actually very sure^^